# Do while не передает значение в новый for

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, while, php, sql

И как сделать правильно?

```
        $allstud=mysql_query("select `фио студента` from студенты where группа=$g") or die(mysql_error());
        $stud=mysql_fetch_array($allstud);
        do  
        {
            echo $stud['фио студента']."<br>";
        }
        while($stud=mysql_fetch_array($allstud));
        for($st=1;$st<count($stud)+1;$st++)
        {
            echo"студен - $stud[$st] группа такая- $g тип такой $lecture дата такая- $lecdate[$st]"; 
        }
```

$stud[$st]  не принимает значения=( из do while

Comment: напишите подробнее что вы хотели получить в цикле for

Comment: значение  из массива $stud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, `mysql_fetch_array($result)` возвращает один элемент массива (`$allstud`), полученного из `mysql_query($query)`. Поэтому в цикле, необходимо создать новый массив:

```
$i = 0;
$stud_array = array();
while ($stud = mysql_fetch_array($allstud)) {
    $stud_array[$i] = $stud['фио студента'];
    $i += 1;
}
```

а далее работать с этим массивом:

```
for ($st = 1; $st < count($stud_array); $st += 1) {
    echo "студент - $stud_array[$st] группа такая- $g тип такой $lecture дата
```

такая-     $lecdate[$st]";
    }

Answer (score 3):

```
    $stud=mysql_fetch_array($allstud);
    do  
    {
        echo $stud['фио студента']."<br>";
    }
    while($stud=mysql_fetch_array($allstud));
```

тут вы наверняка хотели перебрать все строки. Тут будет корректнее использовать этот цикл:

```
 while ($stud=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
     echo $stud['фио студента']."<br>";
 }
```

**Но** результатом этого цикла в $stud будет **false**, потому что он переберет все записи, и если у него нету больше записей, он возвращает false.

**UPD**

Если вы хотите всё это дело перенести в массив таки образом, то можно так:

```
$mas = array();
while ($stud=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   $mas[] = $stud;
}
```

В результате после цикла у нас все строки занеслись в массив из массива (строки и столбцы).

**p.s.** Я вам совету переходить на **MySqli**, там намного удобнее работать, и все источники советуют переходить на него :)

Comment: то есть можно записать в новый массив? но как? $mas[]=$stud['фио студента'];
?

Comment: @странныйкраб обновил ответ )

Comment: тогда имея два значения
Вотинцев Сергей
Демьянов Дмитрий 
выводит
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Вотинцев Сергей [фио студента] => Вотинцев Сергей ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Демьянов Дмитрий [фио студента] => Демьянов Дмитрий ) ) 
как мне записать тогда фор чтобы просто фамилия и имя учавствовали for($st=1;$st<count($masst)+1;$st++)
  {echo" студен - $masst[$st] группа такая- $g тип такой $lecture дата такая- $lecdate[$st]";

Comment: @странныйкраб: это уже другой вопрос, а с текущим вопросом разобрались?

Comment: нет т.к если брать итог этого ответа то незнаю как работать со значениями(ключами)
а в другом ответе ...записывается не с первого а со второго значения из таблицы